# Send data from controller to phtml in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, phtml

Send data from controller to Phtml in Magento 1.

I use ajax send data from phtml to controller and handle it. After processing, I want to send the data back to phtml. And put it on

```
<option value = "data">
```

Ex: My data in controller is ABC

I want to put it in like this

```
<option value = "ABC">
```

Comment: So do you want to fill the dopr-down options from your result. right?

Comment: yes, can you help me

Comment: can youplease share the code of your phtml ajax request. and controller responce.

Answer (score 2):

- You need to create an controller action and return JSON data (In your case return whole html for select element) from the controller.
- Use Ajax to call the Controller action and replace the Select options html with the new html from controller using jQuery.

> Sample Controller Action Code

```
public function gethtmlAction(){
  $request = $this->getRequest()->getParam('request');
  // Your Logic
  $responseHtml = ""; // Html content
  $jsonData = json_encode(compact('responseHtml'));
  $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
  $this->getResponse()->setBody($jsonData);
}
```

> Sample jQuery code in phtml

```
jQuery.ajax({
             url : '<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/controller/getHtml',array('_secure'=>true));?>',
             dataType : 'json',
             type : 'POST',
             data: {request:request1},
             success : function(data){
                 jQuery('#select-id').html(data.response['responseHtml']);
                }
            });
```

Hope it finds you helpful.